# Оправданна ли точка с запятой в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, точка-с-запятой

Мне кажется, точка с запятой здесь лишняя. Можно ли просто заменить её на запятую?

*Для сотрудников компании и партнёров Александр останется в памяти личностью яркой, настоящим энтузиастом своего дела; профессионалом, который внёс неоспоримый вклад в жизнь и развитие компании.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точка с запятой обычно ставится между независимыми предложениями, объединяемыми в одно сложное предложение без помощи союзов, особенно если такие предложения значительно распространены и имеют внутри себя запятые (о запятой между независимыми предложениями, объединенными в одно сложное).
В вашем предложении нет несколько независимых предложений. Поэтому о точке с запятой говорить неуместно. 
В вашем предложении лучше поставить тире (в качестве конкретизации приложения "профессионал"). Но и запятая вполне органична, служащая для выделения однородных членов предложения.
Ср.: Проходя вдоль своего ***вагона*** — ***нашего временного жилища,*** увидели мы в окне знакомую физиономию.

Answer (score 1):

Точка с запятой может ставиться между однородными членам, а здесь желательно как-то разделить две темы.

ПРАВИЛО

Распространенные однородные члены предложения, особенно если внутри них имеются запятые, могут разделяться точкой с запятой, например:

Уже давно позади остались расфранченные увеселительные пароходы для экскурсий; выраставший из воды, клокочущий содроганиями поездов вокзал; переливавшиеся звонами металла плавучие доки, в которые были вставлены, как в коробку, яйцевидные, чуть сплющенные корпуса судов (Федин).http://www.tepka.ru/rozental_2/83.html

Comment: Спасибо. Меня тут именно однородные члены и смутили.

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу оснований для точки с запятой.

Сравните:

Во мраке смутно представлялись те же неясные предметы: в некотором отдалении чёрная стена, такие же движущиеся пятна; подле самого меня круп лошади, которая, помахивая хвостом, широко раздвигала задними ногами; спина в белой черкеске, на которой покачивалась винтовка в чёрном чехле и виднелась белая головка пистолета в шитой кобуре; огонёк папиросы, освещающий русые усы, бобровый воротник и руку в замшевой перчатке (Л.Т.).

Здесь действительно распространенные однородные члены, к тому же разного плана: в отдалении стена с пятнами, вблизи спина и т.д.

А у вас "личность, энтузиаст и профессионал".